Show user journal of system account
I have a quadlet-generated service /var/minecraft/.local/containers/systemd/minecraft.container which is enabled, and boots when my system starts whenever I boot the computer. It runs under the minecraft-server user account, which has its home set to /var/minecraft.
This account is a system account. I already had great difficulties figuring out how to start/stop it.
# I expected to be able to do the following:
sudo -u minecraft-server systemctl --user status minecraft.service # Will not work

# However, I really do have to use the -M option:
sudo systemctl -M minecraft-server@ --user status minecraft.service # Works

I am able to see the logs for this service by doing the following:
# I have to manually filter by `_SYSTEMD_USER_UNIT` and `_UID`
sudo journalctl _SYSTEMD_USER_UNIT=minecraft.service _UID=$(id -u minecraft-server)

# Alternatively, just filtering on `_SYSTEMD_USER_UNIT` also works.
sudo journalctl _SYSTEMD_USER_UNIT=minecraft.service 

# These will NOT work, to my surprise:
sudo -u minecraft-server journalctl --user
sudo -u minecraft-server journalctl --user --unit minecraft
sudo -u minecraft-server journalctl --user-unit minecraft
sudo -u minecraft-server journalctl --user --user-unit minecraft

# They all generate this error:
# 
# Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
#       Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
#       Pass -q to turn off this notice.
# No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.

I enabled lingering for my minecraft-server account, and my journald is configured with Storage=persistent, which are common solutions I found when looking up this problem.
Now, I do have this way to view my journal logs, but I fear it is incredibly suboptimal. Quite frankly, it feels a bit jank. How am I properly supposed to access the journald logs for a different user than my own?

Bonus points if someone can also explain why the -M option is needed, and of course, why journalctl won't work.

To allow sudo or other users to read the minecraft-server user's logs, you can add the root user to the systemd-journal group:
sudo usermod -aG systemd-journal root
After adding yourself to this group, you should be able to run sudo journalctl --user --unit=minecraft without encountering permission issues.
The -M option is necessary because systemd is managing a container-like user instance, which operates in its own isolated namespace.
By default, the systemd journal is segmented by users, and user-specific journal files are restricted in terms of access. Even when you use sudo -u minecraft-server, you don't inherit the full privileges of the minecraft-server user when reading logs.
The journalctl command is accessing logs under /var/log/journal/<UID>, which are typically restricted unless you're a member of the systemd-journal group or the adm group.

Thanks for the effort! Sadly, after sudo usermod -aG systemd-journal root, doing sudo journalctl --user --unit=minecraft will simply give -- No entries --.
